# Probability of events expressed in terms of two mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability

I am having trouble answering the following question

If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events, $P(A)=.37$, and $P(B)=.44$:

Find

a. $P(A^C)=1-.37$

b.$P(B^C=1-.44$

c.$P(A\cup B)=.37+.44=.81$

But I am having problem with this part

D.$P(A \cap B)=0$ I think this is zero because they are mutually exclusive

E. $P(A \cap B^C)=$  I am not sure how to this one

F. $P(A^C \cap B^C)$ or this one

Comment: On D, you are right. For E, $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, so $A$ is a **subset** of $B^c$. Thus the required probability is $\Pr(A)$. I will at least for a while leave the last one to you. Draw a picture (Venn diagram) and it may become clear. Or if you like algebraic methods, note that the complement of $(A^c\cap B^c)$ is $A\cup B$.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a Venn diagram? In this simple case, the answers will pop out at you.

Comment: I get a bit confused about what and is in mutually exclusive. Or is add up the two probabilities. And is their intersection. So A=.37 B^C=.56 so is AND subtract.

Comment: Think of probability as weight. If two regions do not overlap and one has weight $x$ and the other has weight $y$, what is the combined weight of the two regions?

Comment: So I guess it would be .37+.56=.93

Comment: Never mind wait A is a subset of B^C that is true so P(A)<B(C) so I guess this mean A union B^C is prob of A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this diagram: [image]
$$$$Could you find your answers?